# Help with で and を in this scenario

Tags: particle-を, particle-で

I think im missing something in the genki books which i cant quite figure out, the exercise is to make suggestions using the cues. The cues include 'see a movie' 'play tennis' etc im stuck on 'study at the library'. I'm confused as study is both the verb and the object at least i think it is, i believe this is what im mistaken on.

Would it be
としょかんでべんきょうしませんか

or would there be an object of the sentence before continuing with をべんきょうしませんか
The vocabulary page says to use を with to study so i think this might be whats throwing me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you say

> としょかんで　べんきょうします

then you're saying,

> I study at the library.

If you say

> としょかんで　べんきょうしません

You're saying, "I don't study at the library".

If you say

> としょかんで　べんきょうしませんか

you're asking a question which is more like an invitation,

> How about studying at the library?

If you want to say something about what you study, you could say

> としょんで　すうがくを　べんきょうします

which would be

> I study math at the library.

It is possible to say

> としょかんで　べんきょうを　します

with this approach if you want to say *I study math at the library* then you would need to say

> としょかんで　すうがくの　べんきょうを　します